# Is there a way to plot a animation of a closed loop system on matlab?

Tags: matlab, controls, matlab-figure

Is there any option on matlab to make a animation of a closed loop system instead a picture?

I tried to use the for loop to vary the simulation time of the step response, for each for loop interaction I tried to use the step () function to simulate one in a second but the simulation function only showed the result the first interaction, plotting the result image instead has to plot several images over time to give the impression of animation.

I expect to see the evolution over time of the step response or the ramp response of a system.

[Code that i tried to make the animation of a closed-loop transfer function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXZ2s.png)

[Error message using getframe and movie in Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqCeN.png)

[Animation of a closed loop transfer function on Matlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWXFd.png)

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You may create a series of plots within a loop and capture each plot as a frame, and then play back the movie using the *movie* function.

An example is as follows:

```
% capture each plot as a frame and store the frames in M

for k = 1:16
    plot(fft(eye(k+16)))
    axis([-1 1 -1 1])
    M(k) = getframe;
end

% play recorded movie frames

figure
movie(M)
```

Here is the reference link:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/record-animation-for-playback.html

As for your case, the code can be modified as follows:

```
j = 0;
loops = 6;
Ini = 0;
End = 1; 

num = [9];
den = [1 2 9];
FT = tf(num, den);
CL = feedback(FT, 1);

figure;

while j < loops

  t = Ini:0.01:End; 

  hold on 
  step(CL, 'y', t);  
  hold off
  axis([0 10 0 1]);

  j = j+1;
  Ini = Ini+1;
  End = End+1;

  M(j) = getframe;

end

movie(M)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: the problem I saw in the getframe is that when I use the step () function, matlab already plots the step function at the same time, matlab does not wait for the loop to finish so that it creates the function animation over time.

Comment: @Max do you want to simulate the system response over [0,1] or [Ini, End]? There may be some mistake in your code, if the latter on is expected. Try to move the t=Ini:0.01:End into the while loop first.

Comment: the idea was to have the step () function inside the loop create the image from Ini to End so after creating this image in the first loop interaction, I would vary the values of Ini and End to create an image after the initial image.
Example: 1st interaction: creates the image from 0 to 1 second, 2nd interaction: creates the image from 2 to 3 seconds and so on, to give the impression of the animation.

Comment: @Max, yes, try to move the "t=Ini:0.01:End" into the while loop first and you can get the expected simulation results on different time intervals. Then you may use the method in the answer to create the animation.

Comment: @WilliamWu I tried to modify the code to use getframe and the movie, however it appeared the error message shown in image 2.

Comment: @WilliamWu Thanks you so much, when it starts to form the animation it starts to crash a bit I think it can be my processor, but when finished processing the images matlab executes the animation again and executes perfectly. Just to improve the animation a bit I changed the movie (M) function to movie (M, 2,5) to slow the animation.